# Firing Up Browser from Server to get the HTML of an SVG updated reflecting real time data Every Hour

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, phantomjs, nodemailer

Hi I am currently working with [node-scheduler](https://github.com/mattpat/node-schedule) and [node-mailer](http://www.nodemailer.com/) in combination. I have successfully implemented an email scheduler where the user can chose to send an email immediately, ever hour, or every day at 9am.

However, one of the things the user can do is add an attachment to the email. This attachment is a PDF version of an SVG rendered on the page using real time data.

When the user schedules an email to send every hour, I would like to find a way to regenerate the PDF that gets attached so that it is up to date with the SVG that would be rendered if the user actually visited the page...it (doesnt make sense to send an email every hour with the same old PDF)

I do not know how to go about implementing this, but after doing some research I think one way would be to fire up some sort of browser from the node code to generate the html of the SVG...so that I can then convert that SVG to PDF every time an email needs to be sent. (...maybe something like PhantomJS...but I've never worked with PhantomJS and have no clue if it's what I need).

The code to convert this SVG into PDF uri is on the client side/ angularJS

Not sure if this question is completely clear but hopefully someone can provide some insight.

Comment: Here's an article on rendering SVG in node /w phantomjs. Might suit you: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/05/26/love-generating-svg-javascript-move-to-server/

Comment: What type of answer do you expect? You should be able to do this with PhantomJS. Just try it.